# How to ask systemd service to reload its environment variables on runtime

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, services

## Question

My C++ application runs as a systemd service. I need to configure it using environment variables, and be able to reload the value of the variables during runtime without restarting the application.

I created a *.conf* file and used the *Environment* directive in it, and I execute daemon-reload after changing the value in the *.conf* file. **But the service does not notice the change.**

I know about the *systemctl reload* command, but I don't know what to set in the *ExecReload* directive.

### C++ application code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    while (true)
    {
        char * cp = getenv("BAR");
        string s = "";
        if (cp)
            s = (string) cp;
        fstream fs;
        fs.open("/tmp/foo", ios_base::app);
        fs << s << endl;
        fs.close();
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Service description

Path: /etc/systemd/system/foo.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Testing configuration reloading

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/foo_application
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

### Service configuration file

Path: /etc/systemd/system/foo.service.d/foo.conf

```
[Service]
Environment="BAR=2"
```

## My previous (re)search

https://serverfault.com/a/590732/379539

https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment is copied into the process' address space when the process is created. Changes in the environment only affect newly started processes, you can't change the environment of a running program from the outside.

You'll need some kind of interprocess communication (IPC) mechanism for what you are trying to achieve, or just simply write a new value into a file and have your program poll the contents of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are willing to restart the service under consideration (i.e. terminate the running process and launch a new one), this won't work. Environment variables are an individual attribute of a process, they are inherited from the parent upon *startup* (i.e. when the parent process `fork`s). There is no way to alter environment variables of running processes (not regarding hacks like directly manipulating the process' memory via `/proc/pid/mem`). Thus, even waking the process up by `SIGUSR1` and having it reread its configuration (as many services and daemons are implemented to do) won't help - the process would find the very same environment variables as before.

For the behavior you ask for I suggest you consider to get configuration parameters from a file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both yours and the previous one are valid answers. I accepted the previous one because it was posted first. But upvoted both of them (will be effective once I have 15 reputation on this site).